# Connection Exception between systems

Tags: java, tomcat, connection, rmi, rmiregistry

This question has been asked many times and I followed the solutions but didn't work.

I am getting

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.155.1.232; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

tried to telnet from my system to `10.155.1.232` `1099` port..I am able to telnet means there is no port issue

also tried to telnet viceversa on port `8090` of my tomcat,again its working

There is no firewall on my system.

Do I need to check if the rmi registry is already running on `10.155.1.232`?

How to check if rmiregistry is working in windows system from cmd?

So Please guide me what can be the issue

StackTrace is as follows:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.155.1.232; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
        at com.solcorp.pathfinder.PathFinderRmiImpl_Stub.callPStep(Unknown Source)
        at com.bsli.gawd.GetGAWDImplSoapBindingImpl.getGAWD(GetGAWDImplSoapBindingImpl.java:343)
        at com.bsli.gawd.GetGAWDImplSoapBindingSkeleton.getGAWD(GetGAWDImplSoapBindingSkeleton.java:
56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.ja
va:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:2
2)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:1
28)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
        ... 34 more
```

Comment: Did you try to connect to the registry from the RMI box itself?

Comment: how to connect to the registry from the RMI box ?

Comment: Presumably you have the rmi registry and not something else running on port 1099? Also, a bit more of the stack trace may help identify where the problem is happening.

Comment: @DaveRlz:: Updated with whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

If you can see rmiregistry.exe from Task Manager you are fine. But I think you are missing security policy.

Look it up: [rmi run tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html) and let me know?